# Efficiently upload data (requests.put) to a REST API from Azure Blob

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-blob-storage

My goal is to upload a directory of files on Azure Blob to a 3rd party REST API which accepts CSV formatted data. There is one file per date, each file is 50 - 100 MB, and there are more than 100 files. My plan is to upload many files in parallel so I do not want to read the data into memory or write temporary files.

The code below works but I have some questions:

1. When I call `get_blob_to_stream` do I have all data in memory at that point? I think I do because I can call gzip.compress() on it
2. Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient? I want to upload large amounts of data quickly (docs to the API I am using even have an example of uploading 1 billion rows in 100 million row chunks (https://developer.domo.com/docs/dataset/import-and-export-data))

   ```
   hook = HttpHook(method=HTTPMethod.PUT, http_conn_id=conn)
   with io.BytesIO() as input_io:
       blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name=cn, blob_name=bn, stream=input_io)
       r = hook.run(
           endpoint=url,
           headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + token, "Content-Type": "text/csv"},
           data=input_io.getvalue(),
           extra_options={"stream": True},
           )
   ```

What I envision is that the data is piped directly from Azure Blob to the REST API